# Using casting in generics in return statement

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have the following classes:

```
public class Base {
   public int someMethod(){...}
}

public class Derrived extends Base {
   @Override
   public int someMethod(){...}
}
```

Also I have a method that return the `List<Base>`

```
List<Base> method() {
   return fetch();
}
```

Method `fetch()` returns `List<? extends Base>` but actually it holds list of instances of Derrived class

```
List<? extends Base> fetch() {}
```

But code that defines method `method()` will not compile. It requires casting to `List<Base>`. Why I need cast it if I always can treat to instances of that collection as instances of Base class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `List<? extends Base>` isn't the same thing as a `List<Base>`, in the same way that a bunch of bananas isn't a fruitbowl.

Consider:

```
List<Derived> x = new ArrayList<Derived>();

// This is valid...
List<? extends Base> y = x;

// This is what you *want* to be valid
List<Base> z = y;

z.add(new Base());

// This looks fine at compile-time... but what would you expect it to do?
Derived d = x.get(0);
```

It's one thing to treat all *existing* elements of a `List<Derived>` as instances of `Base` - but you can't *add* a `Base` to a `List<Base`>, whereas you *can* add one to a `List<Derived>`. There not every `List<Derived>` is  `List<Base>`.

Comment: is it a good solution to perform casting to `List<Base>` in my situation(return type of that method must be of type`List<Base>`)?

Comment: @maks: No, it isn't. It would be better to change your method's return type, if you can...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this because there is no guarantee that someone wouldn't try to insert into the Collection an object of a different sub-class of Base.

What would happen then?

It would *look* ok, but you're basically trying to use two different types of objects in the same collection, something that, as you know, is not allowed.